# Using number_with_precision in Ruby on Rails 3.0.5 on numbers with large precision

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am working on a Ruby-on-Rails 3.0.5 application, which has numerous numeric fields. It has been decreed by those above, that all numeric 'quantity' fields be stored with a precision of 15 (i.e. 15 digits after the decimal place).

In one particular field, the number stored is 99999.999999999900000. To display it on the screen the application is simply doing this

```
<%= number_with_precision(item.quantity, :precision => 15) %>
```

However, this displays the following on the page

```
99999.999999999898137
```

Similarly, when entering 99999.999999999999999 (Yes, that's right. 15 decimal places), the number is then displayed as 100000.000000000000000 even though it is stored in the database with the 9s in all their glory.

I can remove the use of number_with_precision, and just do **<%= item.quantity %>** and this displays it fine, but I believe number_with_precision is needed for localisation (which is important for the application).

So, is this a bug with number_with_precision? Is there another way to format such large precision numbers that works with localisation? Or is this simply unavoidable due to floating-point arithmetic?

I do realise that entering such a ridiculously large number of decimal places is rather unnecessary and that reducing the level of precision is probably the way to go, but I would need a convincing argument to persuade the powers-that-be.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you convert 99999.999999999900000 to 64-binary you get

```
11000011 01001111 1.1111111 11111111 11111111 11111111 11001000 00000000
```

which translates back to

```
99999.999999999898137
```

Not really a bug, the number is just too big to be saved in a 64 bit entry.
I think you either need to find a way to save it 128-bit binary, save it in another way or deal with the lack of precision :)

Answer (score 0):

the <%= any.thing %> converts any.thing to string:
 `any.thing.to_s`

Maybe that's where you bug is. I'm stuck with a bad rails installation right now and can't test.

Try 99999.999999999999999.to_s in irb or/and rails console. Probably you will get 100000.0.

Comment: 99999.999999999999999.to_s does indeed return 100000.0. However 99999.999999999900000.to_s returns 99999.9999999999 and not 99999.999999999898137 as described in my question, so maybe more than one bug here...